# Connecting to TFS with the Cross-platform Command-line Client for Team Foundation Server

Tags: osx-lion

Has anyone used the Cross-platform Command-line Client for Team Foundation Server? I am trying to connect and it's basically giving me no response or a vague error every time I try to connect. I have set up the proper paths and it seems to be responding - just not authenticating. The specific error text, when present is: error: "An argument error occurred"

Comment: What's the "heisman" (error - for the English) , you're getting?

Comment: Either I receive an error: "An argument error occurred" or I get no error at all and the list of commands and their options. It's not very verbose.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the tool authenticate (and move on to even more annoying errors) by providing a profile file in the ~/.microsoft/.../profiles directory.  The easiest way to do this (IMHO) is to install the eclipse plugin and use the GUI to fill in the parameters for establishing a connection to the repository.  This will create a profile file, which you can then refer to in the -profile option on the command line tool.